# Docker stack deploy latest image works even when image is deleted

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have a docker compose file with a container that uses the latest tag:

  `code_site:
    image: code_site:latest
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: any
    volumes:
    - ../../data_to_backup/code_site/drupal_sites:/drupal_www/sites
    - drupal_core:/drupal_www/core
    - php_fpm_socket:/var/run/php-fpm7
    networks:
    - main_net`

I have a process which will rebuild the container. I use it when I want to make changes to my site.

I am investigating a problem where the docker stack deploy command:

`docker stack deploy --compose-file=docker-compose.yml code_site`

(The stack name happens to match the image name but this is a coincidence.)

If I go through the following process:
Delete the code_site:latest image (rmi code_site:latest)
Rebuild a new code_site:latest image 
Redeploy the stack

It will bring up the OLD version of the container. This is confusing, especially as I have deleted the old version.

I have gone further and I deleted the code_site image then I ran the stack deploy command.
The stack deploys successfully still running the old version of the container.

I can use the docker images command and verify that there is no container named code_site:latest so I have no idea how the stack could possibly deploy.

Can anyone explain how the image is coming back from the dead, and what method I should use to get rid of it permanently and force docker stack to use the real image?

Thanks
Robert

## Update 1

code_site is a locally built image
I am running on a swarm but there is only one node in the swarm

Comment: If you are 100% sure you do not have an image in your docker registry with the name code_site:latest then the updated answer should work. If you do have a image in your docker registry with the name `code_site:latest` then you are deploying the image in your registry and you either have to push the new image to the registry or use the `--resolve-image never` option in your `docker stack deploy` command

Comment: I haven't set up any external registries and the docker images command doesn't list code_site:latest. (I removed all code_site images) I am also sure all running and stopped containers have been deleted. I adjusted my rebuild script to add "docker image prune -f" and "docker volume prune -f" commands. This seemed to clear the and new images started getting picked up.  It's interesting that old images hang around even though they are not listed in the "docker images" command and I would like to understand why. Maybe it's related to docker swarm.

Comment: So the problem is not the image but the container started by the image. Since the old containe is still there from the last deploy and has the same name, docker starts that container rather than creating a new one. To prevent this you can build the new image and and use the `docker service update` command to update the container rather than deleting everything.

Comment: No the container is not still there. I deleted all the containers and all the images based on code_site and it still started up with the old version. It wasn't until I added those two prune commands that it started using the newly built version.

Comment: Odd, well glad you got it going, also I updated answer with docker update command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Docker stack deploy will pull the latest image from your docker registry, since '--resolve-image always' is set by default, therefore always resolving to the latest image.  If you don't want this run

`docker stack deploy --resolve-image never [rest of deploy command]`

However, to make it easier to maintain changes, I would suggest using version tags for your images in your registry, such as  `code_site:v1` when code changes push new version tagged  `code_site:v2` and deploy the new image/version using the normal deploy command without `--resolve-image never`.

Also if you plan to add nodes to your swarm you will need to change your command to `docker stack deploy --with-registry-auth` to allow the other nodes to pull the image from your repo.

## Update 1

If you are 100% sure you do not have an image in your docker registry with the name `code_site:latest` then

**this should work**

Run:

```
docker rm $(docker ps -aq)

docker volume  rm $(docker volume ls --format {{.ID}})
```

To check for lingering containers/services:

**List Existing Services**

```
docker service ls
```

**List Running Stacks**

```
docker stack ls
```

**List**  *All* **Containers**

```
docker ps -aq
```

Then redeploy with deploy command

Alternatively to update your service without removing old containers/volumes/images, you can just update your image, then update your service without removing anything.

This will update your service using the new image... no need to stop, remove, then update... Just update.

### Docker Service Update Command

*Run after new image is built:*

```
docker service update [SERVICE NAME] --image [IMAGE NAME] --force
```